# Как узнать id конкретно нажатого элемента , jq

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Есть div с массивом чекбоксов. Как мне узнать, по клику, который элемент я выбрал?
Вот таким образом делаю

```
 $(".cities_list").on('click', function() {
            var ids = $( ".select_cities :checked" ).map(function () {
                return this.value;
            })
           console.log($ids)
    });
```

Таким образом получаю id массивом, он работает не корректно,первый элемент undefined, а второй уже выбранный id, или если отображает два id, то разных то одинаковых.

Все потому, что ищем по всему div`у. 
Можно каким-то другим способом узнать id конкретно "чекнутого" элемента? Что-то похожее mouseup - перехватить именно чекнутый один элемент, а не перебирать весь div??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не очень понятно при чем тут ID, если вы, судя по коду, пытаетесь получить значение. Что вам нужно - разберетесь уже сами, но показываю, как получить и значение, и ID, и на всякий пожарный индекс элемента

```js
var chbx = $('.cities_list :checkbox').on('change', function() {
  console.log('Value: ' + $(this).val() + '\n' + 'ID: ' + $(this).attr('id') + '\n' + 'Index: ' + chbx.index(this));
});
```

```css
li {
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cities_list">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" id="c1" value="100">100</li>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" id="c2" value="200">200</li>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" id="c3" value="300">300</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

P.S. Если важно, чтобы свойство элемента было "checked=true", то делать соответствующую проверку:

```
if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
    // Чекбокс отмечен
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Повесить событие на сам checkbox:

```
$(".cities_list input[type='checkbox']").on('change', function() {
    console.log($(this).val());
    console.log($(this).attr('id'));
});
```